# CPU Temperature Issue

Tags: laptop, cpu, cooling, temperature

Recently I started gaming on my laptop and I'm noticing the CPU temperature, going through the roof basically.
I started monitoring the CPU's usage and temperature while playing the game using Task manager and Open Hardware Monitor which tell me the temperature goes up to but doesn't exceed 84°C while the usage usually sits anywhere below 45%. Usually before I enter the game  have every application possible closed down and even  my network connections while I play.

I am just wondering if this is normal? I've been monitoring regular usage since as well and its usually between 55°C-70°C
.
According to the spec of mine off of [CPU-World](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Bulldozer/AMD-A10-Series%20A10-5745M.html) the maximum temperature for my own CPU is around 105°C.

I'm planning on getting some form of cooling pad soon anyway, but im just wondering would that even help, or should I just stop playing altogether because as I understand it that keeping the temperature that high for so long can be pretty bad news.

Anyway any input would be appreciated.Thanks.

Sorry if this is similar to other questions, but I figured in these cases the details count and id rather not melt my laptop from the inside out.

[Laptop Spec](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-Pavilion-15-p200-Notebook-PC-series/7486459/model/7669108/document/c04571500/)
(The Game is Skyrim BTW if that helps (no mods))

Answer (score 2):

This is perfectly normal. 84C is comfortably below 105C.

Comment: Agreed, one thing to also look at is to make sure the fan intake opening on the bottom of the laptop is not blocked by anything as well as the fan outlet on the side but 84C is fine. I would only get worried if you pushed 90+

Answer (score 1):

Pavilions (not sure if HP laptops in general) are infamous for their temperature problems.

I have a dv7 5050es (I believe 4290us is the equivalent model in the US), and have exactly the same problem: the airflow is awful, loading old games (e.g. Command & Conquer Generals) causes the machine to shut down after around an hour due to high temp.

Putting something below it to increase the distance to the table or desktop (5 cm are usually enough), or putting the machine in a position where the hot air can escape is enough to reduce the temperature drastically and even have the fans slowing down a little.

I'm not saying your machine is the same, but I have the experience of three different HP machines with heat dissipation issues.